Irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(m|n)$
It is well known that the irreducible representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ are symmetric powers of a vector space of dimension $n$. This can be viewed for instance using Young tableaux. I wonder if a similar result exists for the special linear supergroup $\mathfrak{sl}(n|m)$. I tried to look into the literature about it and did not find, and it seems that classical proof doesn't work (That is, the irreducible representations are symmetric powers of a super vector space of dimension $n|m$). It would be quite interesting if there could be other examples of representations besides the classical ones.
Does anyone have any insight?

Some of the irreducibles for $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ are symmetric powers, but most are not.

Do you have any reference for this?

Try Jim Humphreys' "Introduction to Lie algebras and representation theory". At least in characteristic zero, irreducibles for $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ are given by Schur functors, labelled by partitions with at most $n$ rows, and the partitions with one row correspond to the symmetric powers of the natural module.

I strongly suggest you learn the $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ theory properly before trying to understand $\mathfrak{sl}(n|m)$.
